# should I type every thing in the Interface (TypeScript), API Response

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How should I make an create an interface for the API Response, as of know I am writing every property name and their respective type, is there any better way, even if I do not need all the values, but just asking for an easier way to make an interface or Type for the API Response

For example I have pasted a response, as of know not sure what values will I use but how can I just extract all the properties name and type without typing everything.
As I am not sure if I typing is the only way or is there a better way as well?

```
{
"id": "recZkNf2kwmdBcqd0",
"stock": 3,
"price": 25999,
"shipping": true,
"colors": [
"#ff0000",
"#00ff00",
"#0000ff"
],
"category": "office",
"images": [
{},
{
"id": "attaeT2Dex98o2jfW",
"width": 1000,
"height": 667,
"url": "https://www.course-.jpeg",
"filename": "extra-1.jpeg",
"size": 102108,
"type": "image/jpeg",
"thumbnails": {
"small": {
"url": "https://www.course-apct-1.jpeg",
"width": 54,
"height": 36
},
"large": {
"url": "https://www.course-api.ct-1.jpeg",
"width": 768,
"height": 512
},
"full": {
"url": "https://www.cour.jpeg",
"width": 3000,
"height": 3000
}
}
},
{
"id": "attWsZasaaRD1P7mm",
"width": 1000,
"height": 714,
"url": "https://www.course-2.jpeg",
"filename": "extra-2.jpeg",
"size": 84418,
"type": "image/jpeg",
"thumbnails": {
"small": {
"url": "https://www.course.jpeg",
"width": 50,
"height": 36
},
"large": {
"url": "https://www.course-2.jpeg",
"width": 717,
"height": 512
},
"full": {
"url": "https://www.courset-2.jpeg",
"width": 3000,
"height": 3000
}
}
},
{
"id": "attTvaiDcADaAItLw",
"width": 1000,
"height": 650,
"url": "https://www.course-a3.jpeg",
"filename": "extra-3.jpeg",
"size": 107838,
"type": "image/jpeg",
"thumbnails": {
"small": {
"url": "https://www.courseeg",
"width": 55,
"height": 36
},
"large": {
"url": "https://www.course-peg",
"width": 788,
"height": 512
},
"full": {
"url": "https://www.course-api.com/images/store/extra-product-3.jpeg",
"width": 3000,
"height": 3000
}
}
},
{
"id": "attdxQmF0aCH32F",
"width": 1000,
"height": 667,
"url": "https://www.cou",
"filename": "extra-4.jpeg",
"size": 99481,
"type": "image/jpeg",
"thumbnails": {
"small": {
"url": "https://www.cour
"height": 36
},
"large": {
"url": "https://www.co",
"width": 768,
"height": 512
},
"full": {
"url": "https://www.course-api.com/images/store/extra-product-4.jpeg",
"width": 3000,
"height": 3000
}
}
}
],
"reviews": 25,
"stars": 4.9,
"name": "accent chair",
"description": "Random Text",
"company": "marcos"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are plugins for vs code or you can simply use this https://transform.tools/json-to-typescript, if you pass to it a valid json the result consists into typescript interfaces, for example for you code is like this:

```
export interface Root {
  id: string
  stock: number
  price: number
  shipping: boolean
  colors: string[]
  category: string
  images: Image[]
  reviews: number
  stars: number
  name: string
  description: string
  company: string
}

export interface Image {
  id: string
  width: number
  height: number
  url: string
  filename: string
  size: number
  type: string
  thumbnails: Thumbnails
}

export interface Thumbnails {
  small: Small
  large: Large
  full: Full
}

export interface Small {
  url: string
  width?: number
  height: number
}

export interface Large {
  url: string
  width: number
  height: number
}

export interface Full {
  url: string
  width: number
  height: number
}
```